# How to make a field readonly if the field store a value odoo 12?

Tags: odoo

I tried like this given below but its not getting what i wanted,what im trying to aquire is if that field(Char) is updated(stored a value) by model B it needs to be readonly and else by other model fields needs to be not readonly  :

```
<field name = 'name' attrs="{'readonly': [('name','=', True)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a char field is not set in attrs, compare it to `False`, you can find an example in the [account partner view](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/views/partner_view.xml#L144).

***Example:***

```xml
<field name='name' attrs="{'readonly': [('name','!=', False)]}"/>
```

If we use the above definition and try to set the field value, the field value will not be saved because the field is read-only, to avoid that we need to set the `force_save` attribute to `True` to force Odoo to save the value on the read-only field.

***Example:***

```xml
<field name='name' attrs="{'readonly': [('name','!=', False)]}" force_save='True'/>
```

Comment: If you have time feel free to reply,I have one more doubt.How can we keep a notebook page active(active in the sense kept opened when going to another page)and come back to the old page using the bread crump feature ,where the last opened notebook page needs to be open

Comment: When coming back using the breadcrumbs, Odoo restores a controller from the controller stack and destroys all controllers stacked over the given controller then it will execute the corresponding action and clear breadcrumbs which will load the form view and render the notebook node. Odoo will check if a child node has the attribute `autofocus` set to `autofocus` and if not it will try to find the first visible node and set it as the autofocus tab (The tab opened when loading the form view),

Comment: so the tab opened when a form view is loaded is the first visible tab or the tab which has `autofocus` attribute set to `autofocus`.